# Check if URL parameter exists in map

Tags: clojure, compojure

```
(defroutes my-routes
  (GET "/:id" [id] (html/display-thing id)))

(def my-map
  {:id 1 :title "One"
   :id 2 :title "Two"})
```

Is there a nice way to check if the url parameter `id` exists in `my-map` else continue checking if the other routes match? I know you can do something similar with regex like so: `["/:id", :id #"[0-9]+"]` and suspect it might be possible to plug in an arbitrary predicate function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not actually at a REPL, but isn't this as straightforward as returning nil from html/display-thing if there's no id element in my-map? Take a look at (source GET) to see how the macro passes control to the next route if the method or URL don't match.